# How do I include data driven sass values?

Tags: css, sass, multi-tenant

I would like to use SCSS for my site. However, it is a multi-tenanted site, and I would like the CSS values to be **dynamically generated** (from the database) depending on the customer. I do not want to have to create separate design-time SCSS files for each customer.

I've done something similar in the past with CSS, whereby I included tokens in the CSS file which would be replaced by data from the database before the CSS file is returned in the response. Eg,

```
h1 {
    color: $h1FontColor$;
}
```

However, I am not to be able to do this, as the SCSS processor throws an error saying that the `expected value is invalid`.

Is there any way around this? Can the processor be made more tolerant to allow these placeholders through?

The best solution I've found so far is to wrap the value in comments, which can then be used as the placeholder. It's a bit cumbersome though, and has the disadvantage that it doesn't work when wrapped around SASS variables, as the comment does not get copied into the compiled CSS in the correct places:

```
h1 {
    /* $h1FontColor$ */ color: red; /* $$ */
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `separate design-time`?

Comment: Why don't you just have 1 overlapping site-specific CSS ID Selector, such as `#site--A` vs `#site--B` that is set at the site data level and placed in the html or body tag? That way you can override base styling by starting with `body#site--A { h1 { .. } }`. You could also serve the correct CSS compiled bundle based on that site selector, such as serving up `href=/css/compiled/site--A.css`. If you're storing font colors in something like a CMS per site level and you want them directly injected into the CSS at runtime, you should take a look at Jelo.CSS

Comment: @yashu Some CSS values are stored in the database. I don't want to have to hard-code them in separate CSS files.

Comment: @ben that does not solve the problem. it's not the selectors that need to be dynamically generated. it's the css values - these are stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found a better solution: [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). Simply reference the property from the SCSS file. We are still choosing to use SCSS variables, but that might be unnecessary - we may be able to bypass them entirely to use the native CSS custom properties instead.

```
$primaryColour: var(--primary-colour);
$secondaryColour: var(--secondary-colour);
$fontColour: var(--font-colour);
```

The SCSS compiles without problems with the CSS custom properties retained in the output CSS. The values for the properties can be changed at run time. Unfortunately, Internet Explorer doesn't support custom properties, but we are using [css-vars-ponyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-ponyfill) to support IE11.

Answer (score 1):

For that, I suggest compiling and caching your sass on request (server-side). Shopware uses a [similar approach](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/aac0e5c964ac58b33cb95a6583285df2042d2ade/engine/Shopware/Components/Theme/Compiler.php#L186) [generating a .less config](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/aac0e5c964ac58b33cb95a6583285df2042d2ade/engine/Shopware/Commands/ThemeDumpConfigurationCommand.php#L53) and delivering the css on demand.

Generate a .scss variable file containing variables like $h1FontColor, consume it in your main.scss and compile your files with (depending on your stack) [node-sass-middleware](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware) for express/nodejs-servers or [scssphp](https://github.com/leafo/scssphp) for PHP on the fly.

Comment: Yes, that may be the best way. Our UI is angular, but we also use .Net. Here is a similar solution: https://stevekennaird.com/dynamic-variables-in-sass-scss-with-aspnet/.

Comment: Well then, glad I could help!